# I get error connection Nest with Google Error 400 : redirect uri mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nest, account

I can't sign in a Nest with Google. I get a error code 400 : redirect uri mismatch. I add `account.google` and also nest services to URLS accepted in Google Cloud Console, but I get this error.

[image: Screenshot Error (In French)]

How I can resolve this?

I tried to add URLs of Google account and nest to Google Cloud Console.